# hbase spark module not found

Tags: maven, apache-spark, hbase

I'm trying to access hbase from spark.

```py
spark = (
    SparkSession.builder.master("yarn")
    .appName(app_name)
    .config("spark.jars.packages", "org.apache.hbase:hbase-spark:1.2.0-cdh5.16.2")
    .getOrCreate()
)
```

But I get the error :

> module not found: org.apache.hbase#hbase-spark;1.2.0-cdh5.16.2

The page exists on maven : https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.hbase/hbase-spark/1.2.0-cdh5.16.2

What could be the issue ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

as this page says:

> this artifact it located at Cloudera repository (https://repository.cloudera.com/artifactory/cloudera-repos/)

while Spark by default, resolves only from Maven Central, and Spark Packages repositories.

You need either pass this URL as `--repositories` in the command-line, or specify it in the Ivy configuration file passed via `spark.jars.ivySettings` setting.  See [Spark documentation for more details](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.2.0/configuration.html).